# XForms repeat problem

Tags: xml, xforms

I have a bit of a problem with rendering the content of my XML file with XForms. I don't have that much experience with it so if someone can give me a hint that would be great.

My XML looks something like this:

```
<schedule>
  <day>
    <course> 
    </course>
    <course>
    </course>
     ..
  </day>
  <day>
    <course>
    </course>
    ..
  </day>
  ..
</schedule>
```

If I say

```
<xforms:repeat nodeset="day/course" id="whatever">
   <!-- here handling of nodes -->
  </xforms:repeat>
```

I get only the first course of each day...How should I change it so I get for all courses of a day the nodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeat you have there should iterate over all the `<course>`, of all the `<day>`. For instance, the following shows: Math, Physics, English, History.

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
            xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xhtml:head>
        <xhtml:title>Repeat</xhtml:title>
        <xforms:model>
            <xforms:instance>
                <schedule>
                    <day label="Monday">
                        <course label="Math"/>
                        <course label="Physics"/>
                    </day>
                    <day>
                        <course label="English"/>
                        <course label="History"/>
                    </day>
                </schedule>
            </xforms:instance>
        </xforms:model>
    </xhtml:head>
    <xhtml:body>
        <xforms:repeat nodeset="day/course">
            <xhtml:div>
                <xforms:output value="@label"/>
            </xhtml:div>
        </xforms:repeat>
    </xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

But often, what you want to do is first iterate over the days, then over the courses, as in:

```
<xforms:repeat nodeset="day">
    <xhtml:div>
        Day: <xforms:output value="@label"/>
        <xforms:repeat nodeset="course">
            <xhtml:div>Course: <xforms:output value="@label"/></xhtml:div>
        </xforms:repeat>
    </xhtml:div>
</xforms:repeat>
```